# How to write an email to inform the overseas colleagues that I return to work after the surgery?

Tags: colleagues, email

Today I am back to work after having heavy surgery and a month of sick leave. I used to work with overseas colleagues and I'd like to inform them that I've come back to work. What is the best way to write this email?

Comment: If that's really what you want to do, what's wrong with what you just typed here? I don't see the point to it, only your manager needs to know about your health conditions and even then only really in general terns, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Thank for your swift reply, the reason that I need to inform them as I told them before I take this leave and I received a lot of blessing & message from them, so I'd like to tell them I am back and the surgery went well.

Answer (score 7):

I'd keep it short and professional - you're not using a social network, but there's nothing wrong with letting people know you're back and OK, especially if they already know you've been away for surgery. I'd write something like

> Hi all,
>
> This is just a quick note to say that I'm back at work as of today. I appreciated all the messages of support I received, and I'd like you to know my surgery and recovery went well.
>
> If there's anything that came up in my absence that needs my attention then please let me know.
>
> Thanks,
>
> JoyKitty

I wouldn't send it to the whole organisation or a large mailing list, limit it to people/teams you work with who have a business reason to know you're back, or who you're socially close to (but not so close that they already know from outside work).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness and writing! I'll send to a group that I work closely with and who know I have surgery before.

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Joykitty No problem. I'm really happy your surgery and recovery went well :)